# React native navigation to second page

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I want to create a basic `ScrollView` in which the first page will be visible and it will take the full height of the screen.
When user clicks my button I want to scroll to the second page which will also occupy the full height of the `ScrollView`
What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

1 - Animation while navigating true screens if you are using react-native-navigation [see this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/shared-element-transitions/)

specially this part: ["vertical - The gesture to close the screen will start from the top. For animations, screen will slide from the bottom."](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#animation-related-options)

2 - With vertical FlatList that scrolls 1 Component per screen size/height (I do not recommend this but it depends on the needs if it's walkthrough or something similar)

Ps: You are asking for navigation in the title of the question and for scroll in the question so decide what will work best for you.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve a full-screen, scrollable interface where each page takes the full height of the screen, and you can navigate between pages by pressing a button, you can utilize a combination of FlatList and ScrollView. Here's a step-by-step guide:

**1. Define Your Pages:** First, outline the structure of each page you want to display. This can be done using an array of objects, each representing a page:

```
const STEPS = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Screen1 Title',
    component: <Screen1 />,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Screen2 Title',
    component: <Screen2 />,
  },
  // Add more pages as needed
];
```

**2. Setup FlatList:** Use a FlatList to handle the horizontal paging between each full-screen view. Ensure the FlatList is configured to snap to each page and disable scroll indicators for a cleaner look:

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { Dimensions, FlatList, ScrollView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;

const YourComponent = () => {
  const ref = useRef();
  const [currentSlideIndex, setCurrentSlideIndex] = useState(0);

  // Function to navigate to the next page
  const goToNextSlide = () => {
    const nextSlideIndex = currentSlideIndex + 1;
    if (nextSlideIndex < STEPS.length) { // Ensure we don't exceed our page array
      const offset = nextSlideIndex * WIDTH;
      ref?.current?.scrollToOffset({ offset, animated: true });
      setCurrentSlideIndex(nextSlideIndex);
    }
  };

  return (
    <FlatList
      ref={ref}
      data={STEPS}
      keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
      snapToAlignment="start"
      decelerationRate="fast"
      snapToInterval={WIDTH}
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      horizontal
      bounces={false}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <ScrollView
          style={styles.container}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
          {/* Conditional rendering based on current slide index */}
          {currentSlideIndex === item.id - 1 && item.component}
        </ScrollView>
      )}
      scrollEnabled={false} // Disable FlatList scroll to control it via button
    />
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: WIDTH,
    height: '100%', // Ensure full height
  },
});
```

The **goToNextSlide** function is triggered by a button (not shown in the snippet) to navigate to the next page. Remember to replace `<Screen1 />` and `<Screen2 />` with your actual component content.

This approach provides a smooth, app-like paging experience that can be easily controlled programmatically and is highly customizable to fit your specific needs.

Comment: AI generated content is [currently banned](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/20153035) on Stack Overflow. Please read the [AI Policy](/help/ai-policy) for more information.

Comment: Let me state that my answer is not AI-generated; it’s a custom solution to tackle this problem.

Comment: @HammadAnwar AI-assisted, perhaps?  For grammar?

Comment: Yes, and for code formatting 

Comment: @HammadAnwar Apologies - I missed your response since it didn't @ tag me.  Please be careful here - While I personally wish that it was possible to use AI to assist with grammar and code formatting, unfortunately it is still against the rules.  The (good) reason for this is that LLM's typically modify and/or add content that wasn't in your original answer.